# Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : NA in probability vector

Tags: raster, kernel-density

I want to create a species distributions model (predict habitat suitability for a species in Chile based on occurence records and enviromental layers (predictors)). Therefore, I need to create background points which lie within a kernel-density raster (based on my occurence points). When I run the last part of the code I get the error: Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : NA in probability vector.

```
presences <- which(values(occur.chile) == 1)
pres.locs <- coordinates(occur.chile)[presences, ]
dens <- kde2d(pres.locs[,1], pres.locs[,2], n = c(nrow(occur.chile), ncol(occur.chile)))
dens.ras <- raster(dens)
dens.ras2 <- resample(dens.ras, predictors)
bg <- xyFromCell(dens.ras2, sample(which(!is.na(values(subset(predictors, 1)))), 10000, prob=values(dens.ras2)[!is.na(values(subset(predictors, 1)))]))
```

Comment: Can you please make a small reproducible example (see the R help files to reproduce this)? Also, can you split the last line into individual statements so that we can see where the error occurs (it is hardly readable like this)?

Comment: I found the solution: I needed to set the NA values to 0: dens.ras2[is.na(dens.ras2[])] <- 0